# Cannot install phpmd through composer

Tags: php, jenkins, composer-php, phpmd

I have this in my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "phpmd/phpmd:": "1.4.0"
}
```

When I do:

```
php composer.phar update
```

I get:

Problem 1
    - The requested package phpmd/phpmd: 1.4.0 could not be found.

In the documentation they say it can be isntalled through composer with the line I used - "phpmd/phpmd:": "1.4.0".

But it's not working.

http://phpmd.org/download/index.html

Why?

Comment: I retagged your question, what had this to do with zendframework-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `phpmd/phpmd` package is at packagist (https://packagist.org/packages/phpmd/phpmd), the default repository for composer to search for packages. Not being able to locate phpmd sounds like you either have an offline system, a problem with your network or packagist.org had a timeout.

/edit:

I see you have a typo. Don't write `phpmd/phpmd:` but `phpmd/phpmd` (without the trailing colon).

Comment: No, I can install any other library with composer (phpcs, phpunit, doctrine, symfony, zend framework 2). Only phpmd fails.

Comment: Before I wrote this down I tested it (and now I write this comment, I did it again). Both times I installed phpmd without any problem. The exact line I require is `"phpmd/phpmd": "1.4.0"`

Comment: I added some check so that next time you'll see: The requested package phpmd/phpmd: could not be found, it looks like its name is invalid, ":" is not allowed in package names.